# Sort with mongo and return specific objectId´s first

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

a structure like this:         // (id´s simplified)

User:

```
{_id : ObjectId("4"), name: "Max Sampleman"}
{_id : ObjectId("5"), name: "Jon Doe"}
```

Books:

```
{_id : ObjectId("1"), title: "MongoDB Overview", "likes": 3, contributor: ObjectId("5") }
{_id : ObjectId("2"), title: "NoSQL Overview", "likes": 2, contributor: ObjectId("4")}
{_id : ObjectId("3"), title: "Tutorials Point Overview", "likes": 6, contributor: ObjectId("5")}
```

Now I'm looking for a way to find the books, `sort` them by likes, but return the ones from user 4 first.

An approach like this doesn't seem to work:

```
user4 = await User.findById(4)

books.find({}).sort({contributor: user4.id, likes: -1})
```

It returns an error, saying:

> "message": "Invalid sort value: { contributor: 4 }"

Is there a way to achieve that kind of sorting?

Comment: You can do in a single query. `books.find({contributor:user4.id}, null, {sort: {likes: -1}}).then().catch()`  Make sure that user4.id is notnull with type ObjectID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values allowed for `sort` are `asc, desc, ascending, descending, 1, and -1`, so you will not be able to pass the id instead of these values.

One way to achieve your requirement would be with `aggregate` and `$set`, You can add a new field and set it to `true` for the particular `id` you need to get first and use that field in while sorting.

```js
books.aggregate([
    { $set: { priority: { $eq: ["$contributor", user4.id] } } },
    { $sort: { priority: -1, likes: -1 } },
  ]);;
```

Comment: Additional question. How does this perform vs doing two normal (non-aggregate) queries ? First query to get the contributor´s books and the second for non-contributor and merge them in the end ? Which of course isnt ideal, but just out of curiosity